# What is this hairstyle called?

Tags: characters

Now, here is the hairstyle in question:

[image: anime picture with the haistyle in question]

The character in the image has nothing to do with the question itself. It simply was the closest depiction about the hairstyle that I found. At first I only thought of it as medium length fluffy hair, but describing it that way to a friend of mine didn't get the intended idea across so I'd like to know what the proper way to call it is. What is this hairstlye called?

Comment: @Ghajini If so, can you provide me an alternative site to ask such questions? (Preferably one for writing purposes).

Comment: @Ghajini If you think a question is off topic, then please do not answer it. Answering in comments also bypasses the quality control mechanisms of the site.

Comment: This question is likely to be migrated  to our sister site [english.se] shortly.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *Foolish*! This is not directly related to writing terminology and as such is close to a "What should I write?" request, which is off-topic here on Writing. Questions here should focus on the craft of writing. When searching for words to use in certain circumstances [ELU.SE] is often the better place to ask, but I am not sure about their specific guidelines. It would be best to check out their help center and tour and then maybe ask for this question to be migrated there. Have fun on the site!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a bob with full bangs. The fluffiness comes from having thick hair.

Comment: "Bangs" is not understood by all native English speakers. It is also known as a fringe, which is possibly not understood by people calling it "bangs".